# How to associate some data to each partition in spark and re-use it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-2.0

I have a partitioned rdd and I want to extract some data from each partition so that I can re-use it later. An over-simplification could be:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("1-a", "2-b", "3-c"), 3)
val mappedRdd = rdd.mapPartitions{ dataIter => 
    val bufferedIter = dataIter.buffered  

    //extract data which we want to re-use inside each partition    
    val reusableData = bufferedIter.head.charAt(0) 

    //use that data and return (but this does not allow me to re-use it) 
    bufferedIter.map(_ +  reusableData)
}
```

My solution is to extract the re-usable data in a rdd:

```
val reusableDataRdd = rdd.mapPartitions { dataIter => 
    //return an iterator with only one item on each partition
    Iterator(dataIter.buffered.head.charAt(0))
}
```

and then zip the partitions

```
rdd.zipPartitions(reusableDataRdd){(dataIter, reusableDataIter) => 
    val reusableData = reusableDataIter.next
    dataIter.map(_ + reusableData)
}
```

I will get the same result as `mappedRdd` but I will also get my reusable data rdd.

Is there a better option to extract and re-use the data? Maybe more elegant or optimized?

Comment: What kind of output do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: mappedRdd.collect returns Array[String] = Array(1-a1, 2-b2, 3-c3).... the seme returns my other zippedRdd... but that's just an oversimplification ... What I want is to be able to re-use the data obtained from each partition